# Firestore - Listen to specific field change?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How can I listen to a specific field change with firestore js sdk ?

In the documentation, they only seem to show how to listen for the whole document, if any of the "SF" field changes, it will trigger the callback.

```
db.collection("cities").doc("SF")
.onSnapshot(function(doc) {
    console.log("Current data: ", doc && doc.data());
});
```

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You can't.  All operations in Firestore are on an entire document.

This is also true for [Cloud Functions Firestore triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events) (you can only receive an entire document that's changed in some way).

If you need to narrow the scope of some data to retrieve from a document, place that in a document within a subcollection, and query for that document individually.

Comment: Isn't that a big drawback compared to the firebase realtime database solution ?

Comment: Yes, this is known difference in behavior, and been discussed in various forums.  If all you want to do is locate an existing key in the database and listen to changes, that's much easier in RTDB.  In fact, there are a bunch of other known advantages (currently), documented at the end of this blog: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/10/cloud-firestore-for-rtdb-developers.html

Comment: Does anyone know if they have plans to make this a feature? Especially with Cloud functions.firestore.document().field('myField/subFieldEtc').onUpdate()?

Comment: So basically the rtdb advantages are gone and we are left with docs and collections to work with? Firestore forces the user to have endless doc/collection chains. What I like about firebase is that it felt natural to what programmers are used to do. Pushing, splicing, slicing of arrays but in a realtime db way. Firestore feels counter intuitive imho.

Comment: @Michelangelo If you prefer Realtime Database for your app, then you should use it.

Comment: @DougStevenson Thnx for reading this. I like the products btw and tried Firestore for the first time. Just putting my thoughts out there. Firestore in some ways does help with structuring data. Alternating between docs and collections is simplifying it a lot, but I don't feel in control. Could be me, using it for the first time. I don't know if I will stick to it ;), will see. Ciao!

Comment: @DougStevenson does this affect the amount of data returned? if one field changes in a document of say, 30 fields, the entire document gets returned, and more greatly affects your firebase bill?

Comment: @Jim Yes, if that is a concern of yours, you should split off the fields that can change rapidly into a different document, so that you don't pay the cost of the ones that don't.

Comment: @DougStevenson yikes...if `change.doc.data()` is used does that mitigate all the other data-reading regarding the billing aspect?... or is all the document data still transferred and counts towards billing, with only the changes are accessible?

Comment: @Jim I doesn't matter what you do inside the callback.  The entire document is always read with the assumption that you might need to use any of it at any time.

Comment: There's a lot of misconception in this thread about what data gets pushed to the client when a single field is changed on a document. If you watch the video embedded in https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen you'll hear him explain that *only changed data* is sent, and the rest passed in DocumentSnapshot comes from the cache.

Comment: @cjcurrie For listeners only, changed *documents* are pushed, and the entire document comes along with it.  Unchanged documents previously obtains from the query come from memory cache.  There is no field granularity in this.

Comment: Dang, I guess I misunderstood that. He does say "changed document(s)".

Comment: Using subcollection would be a nice though if it'll be possible delete the subcollection when i'm deleting the parent doc .... but we CANT !

Comment: @cicciosgamino Yes, you can. https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/delete-collections

Comment: @DougStevenson yep i've read about it, but in lots of use cases i think it's not the right way try to handle that pathway ... i'm experienced lot of friction to handle the collections in a documents if the items are few and not many ....

Answer (score 8):

As Doug mentioned above, the entire document will be received in your function. However, I have created a [filter function](https://gist.github.com/christianlacerda/8de3de6af5862c63f02db6f3eaa9334a), which I named `field`, just to ignore document changes when those happened in fields that I am not interested in.

You can copy and use the function `field` linked above in your code. Example:

```
export const yourCloudFunction = functions.firestore
.document('/your-path')
  .onUpdate(
    field('foo', 'REMOVED', (change, context) => {

      console.log('Will get here only if foo was removed');

    }),
  );
```

**Important:** The `field` function is not avoiding your function to be executed if changes happened in other fields, it will just ignore when the change is not what you want. If your document is too big, you should probably consider Doug's suggestion.

Comment: This is a nice function. It might help some people if you explained it a bit further in the answer I think.

Comment: Do you have it translated to `JavaScript`?

Comment: @AlitonOliveira you could convert it using http://www.typescriptlang.org/play

Answer (score 0):

Listen for the document, then set a conditional on the field you're interesting in:

```js
firebase.firestore().collection('Dictionaries').doc('Spanish').collection('Words').doc(word).collection('Pronunciations').doc('Castilian-female-IBM').onSnapshot(function(snapshot) {
                      if (snapshot.data().audioFiles) { // eliminates an error message
                        if (snapshot.data().audioFiles.length === 2) {
                          audioFilesReady++;
                          if (audioFilesReady === 3) {
                            $scope.showNextWord();
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }, function(error) {
                      console.error(error);
                    });
```

I'm listening for a document for a voice (`Castilian-female-IBM`), which contains an array of audio files, in `webm` and `mp3` formats. When both of those audio files have come back asynchronously then `snapshot.data().audioFiles.length === 2`. This increments a conditional. When two more voices come back (`Castilian-male-IBM` and `Latin_American-female-IBM`) then `audioFilesReady === 3` and the next function `$scope.showNextWord()` fires.

Comment: How can i listen one specific field of whole collection using cloud function in cloud firestore.

Answer (score -2):

Just out of the box what I do is watching before and after with the before and after method

```
const clientDataBefore = change.before.data();
console.log("Info database before ", clientDataBefore);

const clientDataAfter = change.after.data();
console.log("Info database after ", clientDataAfter );
```

For example now you should compare the changes for a specific field and do some actions or just return it.

Some more about before.data() and after.data() [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events)

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events
This is the Documentation of "google cloud functions - Cloud Firestore triggers".
And this is totally different story with this topic - using Firestore onSnapshot with javascript.